# Sharepoint Data View "Attempted to use an object that has ceased to exist" Error

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have created a **sharepoint2010 Web Part Page** with 9 data views from a single source which is a sharepoint custom list. from past one week this new error is being shown **"Attempted to use an object that has ceased to exist"**. Now the major problem is that i only get this error during day  time before 1.30 PM IST. Can any one help me with a solution as to why this error is coming and how do i fix it.

Comment: It is likely that there is a job scheduled to run around that time that triggers the error. You should be able to find more from SharePoint logs.

Answer (score 1):

This error means that you're accessing an object that *has been already disposed*. You may find the callstack of the error occurrence in the SharePoint log if you cannot catch it in your code.

Check places where you use `using(...)` or `Dispose()`. You should dispose only objects that *you created* by constructor (like `new SPSite(...)`) or by opening method calls (like `site.OpenWeb(...)`) but *not that you obtained* from delay-initialized properties (like `site.RootWeb`). Similarly, you *must not dispose objects obtained from context properties* (like `SPContext` or `HttpContext`). Those properties are backed up by the actual object that is created first when they are accessed and SharePoint takes care of their disposal.

You'll find these articles interesting:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa973248(v=office.12).aspx
 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb687949(v=office.12).aspx

--- Ferda